# Split View To another Full View Controller in iOS

Tags: ios

I am using split view controller in my app. how to navigate  from tableview cell in detail view(split view) to another full view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to navigate from detail(split) to another full view controller or non split viewcontroller you have to make the nonsplitviewcontroller to  root view controller in case you want to navigate next from that viewcontroller you should use navigation controller.